# Crystal report appearing blank, only the report viewer is being shown

Tags: asp.net, crystal-reports

When I go on the Crystal Report page in my asp.net application, it only shows the Crystal Report viewer, and on the page text box it shows the 1 digit like 1/1 on clicking on the text box and pressing enter the report shows up....what could the problem be?

It is kind of refreshing the report through the Crystal Report viewer.  Previously it was giving the bobj error and when I copied all the folders in the required location now it is giving this error..does anyone know anything about it?

Answer (score 0):

```
Crystal Report TroubleShooting
1.  Bob is undefined, copy file under IIS default folder wwwroot's aspnet_client to web site's place
2.  Invalid Index => alias name not same with stored procedure name
3.  Remember to verify database
4.  try to exec stored procedure in management studio and make sure select explicit field name instead of *
5.  try to preview crystal report
```

I have met this problem before, but my case is that it is not actually blank, try to highlight, it will show invisible word, or by paging, it is mainly due to version conflict in your computer, correct installation priority or install only one version can solve this problem